# Database url environement variable for Debezium Connect

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

Where can I find the environment variables listed for the Debezium Connect docker image?

In the example tutorial and example compose you link the containers (`postgres` or `mysql`) with the `--link` / `links` but I need to be able to inject an environemnt variable instead of the `link` property. I am using postgresql.

The variables are not listed on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect/

Comment: Have you checked this?: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/tutorial.html#starting-mysql-database

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this tutorial but it also uses the `--link` option and does not give the environment variable for the db url

Answer (score 0):

There is no such variable because Kafka Connect (Debezium) doesn't read env-vars into its connector configuratons, only the worker configuration.

Note: `--link` is a deprecated feature of Docker

Comment: True about `link` being deprecated but according to the debezium documentation it's the only way to hookup the containers.

Comment: It's not the only way. You'd use Docker Compose. The documentation author doesn't need to necessarily give Docker specifics, however, and no one has bothered to update it